# How Do I Retrive A Value From Datagrid View?

Tags: vb.net

I am desiging a form with `DataGridView`. When I click a cell in the `DataGridView` it should display the 1st cell's value of the selected row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If InlineAssignHelper(DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count, 0) Then
        TextBox1.Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        TextBox2.Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        TextBox3.Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
        TextBox4.Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

(Or)

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim dr As DataGridViewRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
    textBox1.Text = dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    ' or simply use column name instead of index
    'dr.Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
    textBox3.Text = dr.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
    textBox4.Text = dr.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

And add the following line in your load event

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This will display the first selected value on the row you clicked.

```
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim selectedItem As String
rowIndex = yourdatagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex()
selectedItem = yourdatagridview.Item(0, rowIndex).Value.ToString 
MsgBox(selectedItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vauge but if i understand it right you want to display the value of a cell (or the value of the first cell in that row) when you click on it in some other control.

In which case use the event handler of the datagrid view such as:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
   'for clicked cell
    Textbox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value
    'for first cell
    Textbox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value
End Sub
```